# SQL and relationships

Tags: sql, database

Flights(flno: integer, from: string, to: string,
distance: integer, departs: time, arrives: time)

Aircraft(aid: integer, aname: string, cruisingrange: integer)

Certified(eid: integer, aid: integer)

Employees(eid: integer, ename: string, salary: integer)

I need help with SQL and relationships for this query:

Find the ename and salary of the employees that can fly all aname.

Comment: Did you try anything and got stuck?

Answer (score 1):

```
 select ename, salary from employees where eid in (
    select eid from Certified where aid in (
        select aid from Aircract where aname = <your aname>
    )
 )
```

I don't think Flights come in to your question.

Comment: _Find the ename and salary of the employees that can fly all aname._ Your answer doesn't do this. +1 for effort though. What you want is relational division.

Comment: It doesn't work because the question asks for the names of the pilots that are certified for all aircraft there is and not just for a particular one.

Comment: Not sure I agree with you there. The question is possibly ambiguous.  It states "all aname", not "all aircraft", so it would be reasonable to assume "all aircragt with a particular aname".

Comment: I didn't find it ambiguous at all, so I guess we'll have to agree to disagree on that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT ename, salary from 
 employees E
 where not exists ((select A.aid from aircraft A) 
                  except
                  (select C.aid from certified C
                   where C.eid=E.eid))
```

So, basically what you're doing here is selecting an employee such that the difference between the total aircraft set and the set of aircrafts that he/she flies is an empty set i.e 
if the

> **set of all aircrafts is A and set of all aircrafts that an employee flies is B, then A-B should be equal to {}**.